# Улучшение запроса linq to entity

Tags: c#, запрос, linq

Есть функция, которая отдает объкты, которых нет в БД по пришедшему списку. Как видно, с помощью `Read` я сначала считываю все данные, а потом отбираю. Как я могу избавиться от этого `Read()` чтобы ускорить сам запрос???

```
public List<PermDTO> GetPermsNotIn(List<PermDTO> perms)
{
    var res = this.db.PermRepository.Read().ToList();
    var res2 =  res.GroupJoin(perms, r => new { r.kgroup_name, r.perm_name }, p => new { p.kgroup_name, p.perm_name }, (r, p) => new
    {
        id = r.id,
        description = r.description,
        isactive = r.isactive,
        kgroup_name = r.kgroup_name,
        perm_name = r.perm_name,
        count = p.Count()
    });
    var res3 = res2.Where(w => w.count == 0);
    var res4 = res3.Select(s => new PermDTO()
    {
        id = s.id,
        description = s.description,
        isactive = s.isactive,
        kgroup_name = s.kgroup_name,
        perm_name = s.perm_name,
    });
    var res5 = res4.ToList();

    return res5;
}


    public virtual IQueryable<T> Read()
    {            
        return context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking();
    }
```

Comment: Достаточно убрать `ToList()` после `Read()`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не достаточно. Если убрать, то при `group by` будет ошибка: `Sql = "((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<Loyalty.DAL.Models.Backoffice.Perm>)m1).Sql" выдал исключение типа "System.NotSupportedException"`

Comment: `ToList` реально не нужен и абсолютно лишняя операция, которая лишний раз материализует данные. (Для начала можно заменить на .AsEnumerable) Не совсем понятно, почему нужно сливать всю таблицу на клиента, чтобы сравнивать есть объект/нет объекта, почему бы не переложить эту логику на базу данных? Нельзя ли просто базе скормить набор IDшников и использовать Not In? (not in - не самая быстрая операция на сервере, но явно лучше группировок на клиенте) Альтернатива какая-то извращенная придумывается: перегнать perms обратно из PermDTO в Perm чтобы серверная сторона понимала, что это её  класс.

Comment: @AK я бы с радостью кормил список id-шников, как я это сделал с другими 4мя таблицами, но в этой таблицы ключ по двум стобцам, и я не могу применить инструкцию `Contains`

Comment: Виталий, а как вам направление которое рассматривается в [такой статье](https://habr.com/en/post/152417/) - построить expression и передать на сервер? Это первое направление, по которому возможно двинуться (я правда не очень понял что из чего вычитаем. Правильно ли: вернуть perms минус то, что есть в базе?). Второе направление: а зачем вам нужны эти элементы? Чтобы отобразить пользователю или чтобы вставить в базу? Какая более общая задача, которую решаем?

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = this.db.PermRepository.Read().Where(w => w.count == 0).ToArray();
```

тут ты не вытаскиваешь все данные, а только те которые по условию совпадают.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: как это применимо к моему вопросу?

Comment: ну вы хотели ускорить процесс, вот метод ускорения

Comment: как его применить к моей задаче?